# Trouble installing PyQt on Mac, version mis-reading

Tags: python, macos, qt, user-interface, pyqt

So after installing the whole 5.5 Qt package, and installing SIP, and the Xcode command line tools, I get this problem when trying to install the PyQt folder i got from the .gz I downloaded from the website

```
   Joshuas-MacBook-Pro-2:PyQt-gpl-5.5 Josh$ python configure.py -q /Users/Josh/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin -d /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
sh: /Users/Josh/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin: is a directory
Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v3. Use the
--qmake flag to specify the correct version of qmake.
```

However, I clearly have v5.5 of Qt.

Any idea how to fix this or type in a different command to install it directly?

Answer (score 1):

After spending much time getting PyQt working smoothly on a Mac, my strong recommendation is to install PyQt via Homebrew. The steps are very simple:

1) Install homebrew from [here](http://brew.sh/)

2) Edit your ~./bash_profile to include the following at the top, so that later installs will see the brew versions of installs:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

3) Refresh your terminal window:

```
>source ~/.bash_profile
```

4) Then, simply install python, sip, pyqt in that order:

```
>brew install python
>brew install sip
>brew install pyqt
```

You should now have a fully working python/pyqt environment that you can customize via pip etc.